# I need an st_numscalar() example

Tags: stata

I would like to perform calculations in Mata returning a scalar result. I would then like to access that result in a macro in Stata. For example, I type:

`mata: st_numscalar("dog", sum(range(1,4,1)))`

Then I type (in Stata):

`` di `dog' ``

and I then get (nothing):

When I expected to get:

`10`

Thinking that perhaps the macro `dog` needs to exist first, I prefix the above commands with:

`scalar dog = 0`

but no dice.

Then, thinking that scalars are weird, and why not simply use a good old local:

`mata: st_local("dog", sum(range(1,4,1)))`

But this just gives grief (whether or not a local named "dog" with a numeric value is created beforehand or not).

What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, so the issue is my use of single quotes on the Stata side?

Comment: Correct: in your first example you referred to `dog` as if it were a temporary name, but it is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two key points:

Scalars are scalars and macros are macros. But a scalar can have a temporary name, which is where you can get confused.

Macros are strictly strings. Numeric scalars can only hold numbers. (There are string scalars too.)

```
. mata : st_numscalar("frog", 42)
. di frog
42
```

That's a scalar with a permanent name. But watch out: if you had a variable called `frog`, that interpretation would trump the `scalar` interpretation.

```
. tempname toad
. mata : st_numscalar("`toad'", 24)
. di `toad'
24
```

That's a scalar with a temporary name.

```
. mata : st_local("newt", "1000")
. di `newt'
1000
```

That's a local macro, which holds the string `"1000"`.

You can do things like this.

```
. di `newt' + `toad'
1024
```

But that is because two things are happening here. Stata  is first interpreting the references to the local macro and the scalar and substituting their contents. So `display` then sees

```
. di 1000 + 24
```

and does the calculation. But you could insist on a string interpretation.

```
. di "`newt'`toad'"
1000__000000
```

which underlines that you have to keep straight the difference between the name of something and its contents. Here the string

```
"`toad'"
```

is the name of the scalar, which is a temporary name.

Also consider this:

```
. local anothernewt = 1000
. di `anothernewt'
1000
. di "`anothernewt'"
1000
```

Stata lets you specify a numeric interpretation or a string interpretation. Sure, the results look similar, but in principle they are different. The question is whether that bites you (not in this example).

Comment: If macros are strictly strings, then why does `local dog = 13` and then ``di `dog'*3`` produce `39`?

Comment: Already explained. Please do read the answer again. `display` understands that `di 13 * 3` means that you want a numeric calculation. `display` never sees the local macro as such, just its contents, as Stata interprets all macro references before any particular command gets to work.